# Hide Windows dialog Box While Excel Cells Going to Merge using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am exporting gridview to Excel in windows application successfully, but the problem is when I am going to Merge some range of cells in that excel sheet, it raises a windows dialogue box. So each and every time I am merging those cells it does not give any exception but it's showing a dialogue box.

I dont want that dialogue box, how do I hide it?

My Code for merging the cells is:

```
wksheet.get_Range(lstGetTotalTitleCells[0].ToString(), lstGetTotalTitleCells[lstGetTotalTitleCells.Count - 3].ToString()).MergeCells = true;

// wksheet.Range[GetRanges[0].ToString(), GetRanges[GetRanges.Count-2].ToString()].Merge();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try setting the `DisplayAlerts` property on the `Application` to `false`?

If you do try this, something to be aware of is that Excel will choose the default response on the dialog.  You can read about the property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts.aspx).